# Test if record exists and choose sql query

Tags: php, sql, ajax, pdo, mariadb

Why my code doesn't work?

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("connecting-to-database.php");

$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `timetables` WHERE `who` = :who");
$query->execute(array(
":who" => $_SESSION["id"]["username"]));

if ($query->rowCount() > 0) {
    $query = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE `timetables` SET `who` = :who, `day` = :day");
    $result = $query->execute(array(
    ":who" => $_SESSION["id"]["username"],
    ":day" => $_GET["timetable"]));
} else {
    $query = $pdo->prepare("INSERT into `timetables`(`who`, `day`) VALUES(:who, :day)");
    $result = $query->execute(array(
    ":who" => $_SESSION["id"]["username"],
    ":day" => $_GET["timetable"]));
}
```

I can't see errors, because I am using AJAX with method GET.

On main website I have:

```
var rocket = JSON.stringify(timetable);

var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("GET", encodeURI("modify-timetable.php?timetable=" + rocket), true);
console.log(rocket);
```

When you have less informations, I could give you some more.

Comment: Please define *doesn't work*

Comment: I have nothing in table in database.. I create timetable (table) on main website and this timetable (table) a encode to JSON and send with GET on modify-timetable.php.

Comment: `rowCount ()` is the number of rows affected by the last DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement executed.

Comment: So what I have to use to find out if exists some record on `who`.

Comment: Also your UPDATE updates everyones record (there is no WHERE clause).

Comment: Ou, thanks, I didn't see it. Could you help me with finding out if exists some record?

Answer (score 0):

Learn how to use IODKU.  It can replace all of the code you presented.

```
INSERT into `timetables`    (`who`, `day`)
    VALUES                  (:who,  :day)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `day` = :day
```

(It does require that `who` be `PRIMARY` or `UNIQUE` key.)